# angular + IIS + internationalization refresh/cache issue

Tags: angular, iis, caching, internationalization

We are running angular 8 on IIS 10. We use angular translate service to support multiple languages.
Sometimes after a fresh deployment the new or modified translations don't get resolved correctly.

For example, we might add the following to the json english internationalization file:

```
   "ABOUT": {
     "CONTACT": "Contact Us"
   }
```

The new html file would contain something like:

```
  <div>{{ 'ABOUT.CONTACT' | translate }}</div>
```

Where translate is a component member of TranslateService  class:

```
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core'
...

constructor(public translate: TranslateService, ...) {
```

And the new menu item would read: 'ABOUT.CONTACT' instead of 'Contact Us'.

Other observations:

1. The literal would resolve correctly in the following scenarios:

   - if we open chrome in incognito mode
   - after we delete chrome browser cache
   - after a certain amount of time
2. Other than the literal not resolving correctly we don't have any problems that might point to a caching issue (we have caching turned off on IIS) and we also disable cache in our index.html.

Comment: How you get the translation file? pack with application or with a request, or like an asset?

Comment: Assets. The angular build places them under assets/i18n.

Comment: I don't know what server technology you use (node or asp.net or etc) you can try versioning.